# What should we name our chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat

[One of the (real) essential questions of a private beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223675/201409) is what to call [**our chatroom**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26589/computer-graphics). Having an active and welcoming main chatroom will hopefully help in forming an active community and surviving the beta phase. Giving it a unique name should hopefully help make this more fun an interesting.

Please post one suggestion per answer and vote according to your preferences.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The Cornell Box

[This thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornell_box):

[image: Cornell Box]

Answer (score 9):

### The Teapot

Teapots are the recurring joke of Computer Graphics, so we'd all discuss things while having tea from our properly rendered teapots.

Comment: Which are themselves made of tea of course: http://3dprint.com/65038/3d-printed-tea-pot-with-tea/

Comment: @Bart-When will this website go to public beta? Please inform me ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

### Direct Illumination

Because you're asking questions, receiving answers directly from other people, and being illuminated as a result.

Comment: Maybe that should be the name of the site itself! :-)

Comment: There is now talk of naming the site itself on Meta: [The name of our programming and research site](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/55/21)

Answer (score 2):

## The dead pixel

the bane of screens

Answer (score 1):

## The Grid

There are grids on the GPU, meshes can be seen as grids and, of course, there is the *Grid* in *Tron*.

Answer (score 1):

## The Render Farm

where computer graphics gets done in bulk.

Answer (score -1):

## The pipeline

like the graphics pipeline.